# Why it's no app logo when i run my project in ios 11 with xCode9

Tags: ios

Its valid in xCode8 and iOS 10, but it not valid after i updated my phone iOS 11 & xCode 9 . And I did nothing with app logo images in AppIcon at Assets.xcassets file.

Comment: Your question is not clear!! Please share your code here

Answer (score 0):

seems to be specific issue with your instance. clean project and derived data and build again.